# Condition for Max Principle for BTCS

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, heat-equation

I'd like to show that for the BTCS for the heat equation: $\frac{{v^{n+1}_{m}}-{v^{n}_{m}}}{k}=b\frac{{v^{n+1}_{m+1}}-2v^{n+1}_{m}+{v^{n+1}_{m-1}}}{h^2}$ the maximum principle $$sup_m||v^{n+1}_{m}|| \leq sup_m||v^{n}_{m}||$$ is satisfied iff $2b\mu \leq 1$.

I have rewritten and collected terms so that the method can be written: $$-b\mu v^{n+1}_{m+1}+(1+2b\mu) v^{n+1}_{m}-b\mu v^{n+1}_{m-1}= v^{n}_{m}$$ where $\mu=\frac{k}{h^2}$

Having trouble with formulating an argument though. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://math.tifrbng.res.in/~praveen/notes/cm2013/heat_1d.pdf) might help.

Comment: You've written down an implicit scheme for the heat equation (since you put $n+1$) on right hand side. This is unconditionally stable and the maximum principle always holds. Your problem is likely asking you to consider the explicit scheme where $n$ appears on the right hand side, then the condition $2b\mu \leq 1$ will show up.